# How to know project is using only TDD

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I want to provide tests statistics of TDD usage in a company, so I need to identify which projects are using only TDD, or if there are tests code written after coding. I thought using time stamp file change info, but Does anybody have a better solution for this?

Comment: Ask the developers?

Answer (score 1):

A pretty broad question, but I think there is actually a fact based answer.

That answer is: you can't solve social problems on the technical layer.

In other words: already your goal/requirement is *flawed*: you will not be able to generate those clear statistics. You might be able to apply some heuristics; but unless you get access to **all** information from **all** developer systems, timestamps wont help you. You see: the normal approach is to do some coding; and at some point release all of that into the version control system.

So, sometimes it might be clear from timestamps that X was written before XTest; but very often, X and XTest will be released into the library within *one* commit. Now - which one was written first?

Thus: start thinking on the "social" level first. Meaning: *talk* to the development teams. Ask them about their practices. And when they *claim* to do TDD; then look into their specific commit history and see if that tells you anything.

Answer (score 0):

Usually following the *Test Driven* Development practice implies continuous repeating of small [Red-Green-Refactor](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/12/17/TheCyclesOfTDD.html#minute-by-minute-micro-cycle-red-green-refactor) cycles. As @GhostCat [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967090/4207332), looking into the commit history is is an excellent point to check if the devs follow TDD principles. Every change in the production code should be *reflected* in a corresponding unit test.

You may also check the [code coverage](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html). The high coverage is not the goal but it can be a good indication if the TDD practices are followed.